# spaCy nlp - replace string

Tags: python, replace, nlp, spacy, matcher

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
import re


nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
document_string= 'Electronically signed by : John Douglas.; Jun 13 2018 11:13AM CST, Adam Smith.'
nlp_doc = nlp(document_string)
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}]
matcher.add('FULL_NAME', None, pattern)
matches = matcher(nlp_doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
     span = nlp_doc[start:end]
     names = span.text
     print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
John Douglas
Adam Smith
```

**I need to replace it to [hidden] and print document_string with show hidden values (previous output)**

**Required output:**

```
Electronically signed by : [hidden].; Jun 13 2018 11:13AM CST, [hidden].
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) here.

```
new_doc = nlp_doc.text
names = []

pattern = [{'POS': 'PROPN'}, {'POS': 'PROPN'}] 
matcher.add('FULL_NAME', None, pattern) 
matches = matcher(nlp_doc) 

for match_id, start, end in matches: 
    span = nlp_doc[start:end] 
    names.append(span.text) 

for name in names: 
    new_doc = new_doc.replace(name,'[hidden]')
```

Result:

```
In [114]: new_doc
Out[114]: 'Electronically signed by : [hidden].; Jun 13 2018 11:13AM CST, [hidden].'
```